# "before" and "want" for the same systemd service?

Tags: systemd, dependencies, systemd-unit

In [this example](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/units/systemd-timesyncd.service.in#L17) of a systemd unit file:

```
# systemd-timesyncd.service
...

Before=time-sync.target sysinit.target shutdown.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target
Wants=time-sync.target
```

`systemd-timesyncd.service` should start **before** `time-sync.target`.
This defines an [ordering dependency](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=).

But at the same `systemd-timesyncd.service` **wants** `time-sync.target`. So `time-sync.target` is it's [requirement dependency](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Wants=)

What is the use case for this relation and why aren't they in some conflict with one another?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The use case of this double relation is similar to a “provides” relation. `systemd-timesyncd` provides a time synchronisation service, so it satisfies any dependency a unit has on `time-sync.target`. It must start before `time-sync.target` because it’s necessary for any service which relies on time synchronisation, and it wants `time-sync.target` because any unit relying on time synchonisation should be started along with the `systemd-timesyncd` service.

I think the misunderstanding comes from your interpretation of “wants”. The “wants” relation in systemd isn’t a dependency: `systemd-timesyncd` doesn’t need `time-sync` to function. It’s a “start along with” relation: it says that the configuring unit (`systemd-timesyncd.service`) wants the listed units (`time-sync.target`) to start along with it.

See also [Which service provides time-sync.target in systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/486146/86440)

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of this mechanism is to ensure that ordering relationships can be made but *do not take effect* unless necessary.

`time-sync.target` is an ordering milestone.  All of the services that provide "time synchronization" specify that they are `Before` the `time-sync.target`, so that the target only becomes ready once "time synchronization" is in effect.  All of the services that need "time synchronization" to be in effect when they run specify that they are `After` the `time-sync.target`.

If the latter also had a `Wants` relationship to that target, then they would *always* end up being ordered by it, as it would always be included in the set of things that are put into order.

This is seen as being suboptimal in the case where there is in fact no concrete "time synchronization" service; and the thinking of the systemd people is that such ordering should not be in effect in such a case.  Rather, services should be ordered as if `time-sync.target` were not there, allowing some of them to be started much earlier if that is their "natural" position without the milestone.

The solution is for `time-sync.target` to actually not be there.  It isn't wanted by the services that expect to start after time synchronization is available.  So it does not exist in the set of ordered things if *only those* services are started.  It is only brought into the set if an *actual* "time synchronization" service is started, with that (rather than the client services) having the `Wants` relationship that brings it in.

Targets do not necessarily have to be collections of services.  They can also be ordering milestones.

There are a fair number of such pure milestones, in systemd and elsewhere.  The `name-services` target in the nosh toolset's service bundle collection is a similar pure ordering milestone.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`system-control`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/system-control.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.

Answer (score 1):

`time-sync.target` is kind of a flag in system, so that services depending on a correct time do not have to depend on systemd-timesyncd, ntpd, whatever.

The `Before` entry tells systemd to start systemd-timesyncd, then time-sync.target (this is just for ordering). The `Wants` tells it to actually set the flag.